# WP cron Executes once and doesnt repeat

Tags: wp-cron

Might be a bad question but im unable to solve it right now.

My WP_cron executes on the starting point but doesn't seem to perform afterwards.

My `functions.php` code is:

```
 add_action( 'my_scheduled_event', 'prefix_my_scheduled_event' );

 if(!wp_next_scheduled('my_scheduled_event')){
   $timestamp = strtotime( '2017-09-28 12:05:00' ); 
   $recurrence = 'twicedaily';
   $hook = 'my_scheduled_event';
   wp_schedule_event( $timestamp, $recurrence, $hook );
 }
```

Additionaly i have added this line to `wp-config.php` to make it work in the first place.

```
 define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Despite its name, `wp_cron` doesn't operate exactly like `cron` on a server. It only gets triggered if and when someone visits the website. Is it possible that it wasn't triggered because there were no visits?

Comment: no im afraid in the time in question i had over 900 page views

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if your server is overloaded on a shared host. Check your server logs or resource use in c-panel. It can also be limited by your host depending on the server configuration.

Comment: Dedicated hosting in place no limits at all in place as all managed by ourselves.